# Wordpress site network, How to use one file folder for all sites?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a multi site network wordpress blog.
There are the following sites

domain.com
domain.com/blog2
domain.com/blog3

When I upload files for domain.com they will be in domain.com/media. That is how I want it. But when I upload files for blog2 (or blog3) they will be in domain.com/blog2/files/ (or domain.com/blog3/files/). I can change the file folder for every site in site settings (admin - settings - miscellaneous). I also was able to set not to use the upload date and everything, but regardless what I do, the files will be in /blog2/files (I entered an other folder: /media).

How can I archive that all files will be stored in domain.com/media and all sites are able to choose the files from there?

Answer (score 0):

Just tell Wordpress to store the medias files in **an absolute folder**.

Go to <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Medias</kbd> > <kbd>Uploading Files</kbd> and paste **the full absolute path** corresponding to domain.com/media (where it says  `"Default is wp-content/uploads"`)

It can be something like `/var/www/domain.com/media` e.g, it really depends on your hosting. Obviously it should be readable/writable as well.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Do you refer to the site settings? So open the settings of the sub blog, for example blog2? I have "Settings" then there is a sub menu called "media". But then there is no sub menu called "uploading files". Only two things to change labeled Media settings" with "Image sizes" and "Embeds".

Comment: if you click on media in the sub menu, you will see in the main page a form saying "uploading files" with two input texts. It is not a submenu, but a form when you click on "media"

Comment: Exactly this one is not there:
http://codex.wordpress.org/images/4/43/options-media.png
I have the two upper menus "Image sizes" and "Embeds", but not  "uploading files". Maybe they removed it in site network installations?
http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Comment: Yes, that is certainly why you cannot set a custom upload folder. If you have FTP access, another alternative is to set up upload folder as symbolic links from blog2 and blog3 to the main media folder. This could work for *nix hosting.

Comment: I am using windows. There is something similar, but the files are only stored there, but not referenced correctly. I am currently trying to use the plugin posted here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-file-upload-folders-on-wordpress-30-multi-site

Comment: This doesn't work either :( The plugin get's installed correct, but then upload is broken. It is uploading the file, but then there is no URL and the file is not there (physically). I think it is because I am using windows and a site network.